# Update column from one table to another only if the id matches on 2 tables and not the third

Tags: mysql

i have 3 tables A B C.

```
|--------A-------|
| ID   | Price   |
|------|---------|
|  1   | 0       |
|----------------|
|  2   | 0       |
|------|---------|
|  3   | 0       |
|----------------|
|  4   | 0       |
|----------------|

|--------B-------|
| ID   | Price   |
|------|---------|
|  1   | 2.00    |
|----------------|
|  2   | 5.00    |
|------|---------|
|  3   | 3.00    |
|----------------|
|  4   | 1.00       |
|----------------|

|--------C-------|
| ID   | Price   |
|------|---------|
|  5   | 2.00    |
|----------------|
|  6   | 5.00    |
|------|---------|
|  1   | 2.00    |
|----------------|
|  2   | 5.00    |
|----------------|
```

i would like to copy B.price to A.price only if B.ID doent not excist in C.ID. in the case it would A.ID (3 add 4). the result shoould look like this

```
|--------A-------|
| ID   | Price   |
|------|---------|
|  1   | 0       |
|----------------|
|  2   | 0       |
|------|---------|
|  3   | 3.00    |
|----------------|
|  4   | 1.00    |
|----------------|
```

Comment: Please revert your edit.  Now no one will be able to help you.

Comment: i did. can people help me now?

Comment: You have to wonder why anyone would want/need to do this. There may be legitimate reasons, but it smacks of poor design.

Comment: I made up this scenario for the sake of simplicity. The database structure is very complicated. Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Use an update join.  The query below does an inner join between the A and B tables, because a match here is necessary to do an update.  Then, we make a second left join to the C table, with the `WHERE` clause restricting to matches between the B and C tables.

```
UPDATE A a 
INNER JOIN B b
    ON a.ID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN C c
    ON b.ID = c.ID
SET a.Price = b.Price
WHERE c.ID IS NULL;
```